# Updating GWT Cell Table at runtime

Tags: gwt, widget, gwt2

I am trying to update a cell table at run time, the cell table gets its date from a list

```
Cell_Table.setRowData(0,AllMessages);
```

I am trying to update the List `AllMessages` then do this `Cell_Table.redraw();` with no success.

I am trying this do this again  `Cell_Table.setRowData(0,AllMessages);` with no success AS WELL

when I am using the same technique to add rows, everything is ok but when i am removing some data from the list feeding it, the cell table is not being updated!

Comment: When using the same technique, i am adding the cell table is being updated but when removing, it not updating

Answer (score 6, accepted):

by
John LaBanca

@ [GWT Discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit/browse_thread/thread/495d6b36834b2eda#)

setRowData(int, List) replaces the range of data.  So, if the list gets
shorted, it doesn't touch the items that appear after the end of the list.

You have to update the row count as well:
table.setRowData(0, NewMessages);
table.setRowCount(NewMessages.size(), true);

Or, you can use the new version of setRowData that does not take a start
index (since GWT 2.1.1):
table.setRowData(NewMessages);